# PC doesn't perform copy from it to sdcard/internal storage

Tags: sd-card, file-transfer, copy-paste

I had create a custom ROM and trying now to copy it from my **PC** to my **Lenovo Ideatab A3000-h**, but when connecting the device and try to copy it from my pc to the device, it didn't do the process and gave me the following behavior (forever):

[image]

the ROM size is about **2GB**, is there's some way to know what's wrong or a safe way to transfer the ROM rather than this way.

p.s. tried to copy another one with a very near size and got the same result, but copying a small-sized files works fine

Comment: Are you able to transfer other file types?

Comment: @sameer yes I'm

Comment: If it's an external SDCard: Why not use a card reader?

Comment: @Izzy unfortunately it's not

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you are trying to copy to IdeaTab I think you should select Internal Storage first.

Comment: Did you try different USB cables? Is there a limit of file size? Remember that your trying to copy,  so is there enough room? I know it shows enough. Is the tablet encrypted? Have you pushed through adb? There are more than one way to skin a cat (figure of speech).

Comment: @Crayon he might have dragged and dropped(copy/paste)

Comment: @HasH_BrowN I did try different usb cables .... about file size limit, i don't kn ow what you are taking about, and who put the limit .... and there is enough room despite i dno also about encryption stuff but it copies other small files without problems(worth to mention I tried another custom room with a very near size and got the same result of this) .... and I don't know why but the adb can't read the device although the pc reads it. pleeeese I stuck in a stupid problem and need a help as my work stopped due to that issue :(

Comment: Did you try mounting the internal storage from recovery and then copying ?

Comment: @sameer No, I didn't

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat or you can try transferring the file through ftp. Look for ftp droid in play store

Comment: @sameer can you kindly tell me how to transfer the file through ftp

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41583/how-to-transfer-files-between-your-pc-and-android-phone-wirelessly/ refer this link

Comment: @sameer i think your comment was the key, I'll upvote it and make a comment show that this is correct if you place if as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ES File Explorer.

How to use:

1. Go into your PC and set up a shared folder. Use this as reference *https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-share-folders-in-windows-7-with-the-shared-folder-wizard/*
2. Either place your file to transfer in the shared folder or make the shared folder where your file is located.
3. Now install ES File Explorer on the device and run the app.
4. Go to the quick access menu (3-dash button in the top left corner).
5. Select *Network>LAN*.
6. Bottom of the screen select *SCAN*, might take a minute to acquire a connection.
7. Select your shared folder.
8. Select your file (long pressing file and select copy at the bottom)
9. Go to the quick access again and select *LOCAL*
10. Pick your destination location from there and tap *PASTE*

Comment: it takes like million minutes to transfer but at least it worked as intended :D

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat I know, but like you said it works. Its got me out of bad spots a couple of times.  Glad I was able to help.

Comment: It's faster if you enable remote manager on ES File Explorer, that way you can access your phone from your pc with any ftp program.

Comment: @Crayon I didn't include that because using FTP you have a 500 mb per individual file limit. Some .zips exceed that size.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN thanks, I didn't know that. I'll try.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN I just copied a 1.8GB file using Remote Manager (FTP) function on ES File Explorer v3.2.0.

Comment: @Crayon was it a single file? I'll have to research that further for a definitive answer. I myself thought there would be a 2GB limit on single file since it is a fat32 format, but 500MB was the "official" figure that kept showing up.

Comment: Yes, single file. fat32 has a limit of 4GB for a single file but that is a file system limit it doesn't change how you transfer the file to.

Comment: @Crayon idk but when trying to enable Remote Manager, it became pretty slower, I just changed the Remote Manager IP to the corresponding one and Turned it ON.

Answer (score 0):

I think the SD or micro SD card on Android is formatted as FAT32 as doesn't allow more than 4GB Copy/Paste from Laptop to it, there is a limitation to it.

Simulated the issue on my laptop and got this error message using TeraCopy app using windows 10, after I mounted the micro sd card directly to the laptop without using the tablet.